# Getting the content of a html file present in a folder - AWS Lamda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a AWS lambda function which has index.js file and I have a html file in a different folder(Pages/test.html).
index.js path - AWSLambda/index.js
test.html path - AWSLambda/Pages/test.html
I want to get the content from test.html and store it in a variable present in index.js. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just read the contents of that file just like you would read any other file with node, e.g.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

(and inside your handler)

const content = await fs.promises.readFile('Pages/test.html', 'utf-8')
```